# C# post file to server

Tags: c#, post, webclient

I'm busy converting a perl script which posts an audio file to a server to C#

this is the perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require LWP::UserAgent; 
my $url = "url";
my $audio = "";
open(FILE, "<" . "test.flac");
while(<FILE>)
{
$audio .= $_;
}
close(FILE);
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->post($url, Content_Type => "audio/x-flac; rate=16000", Content =>   $audio);
if ($response->is_success)
{
print $response->content;
}
1;
```

this is my C# code

```
        string uriString = "url";
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type: \"audio/x-flac; rate=16000\"");
        byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(uriString, "POST", "test.flac");
        string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
```

for some reason it keeps returning a 400 (bad request) error if I run the C# code.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try comparing the requests done by the Perl script vs the C# code with a tool such as Fiddler.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ There is probably a subtle difference you are missing.

Comment: I think the escaped quotes shouldn't be there. Try `"Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000"`.

Comment: Using fiddler I found out that the myWebClient.UploadFile causes the Content-Type to become multipart/form-data so I think I'll need some other way to upload the file

Comment: ok I solved my problem, I just can't post the answer yet, because my reputation isn't high enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple ideas what the problem may be...

1. Use an alternate overload to add the header, this will help ensure it is formed correctly.

   ```
   myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "audio/x-flac; rate=16000");
   ```
2. The paths of the source file name not be rooted the same... Try providing a fully qualified path to the file being uploaded. If that works, then you know where the issue is and do something more appropriate when building the paths.